# What does Power really mean?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, definition, power

I've been trying to solve a problem for some time. I have been given conflicting information by both literature, colleagues and people on this very forum.

It's a very simple question: **What is the definition of [power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_%28physics%29#Mechanical_power)?**

*In particular, I would like to know how constant power would accelerate a constant mass over a fixed distance, assuming that no resistive forces are at work, i.e. no friction, no air resistance, etc.*

I know that power is the rate at which work is done with respect to time, i.e. $P = \operatorname{d}\!W/\operatorname{d}\!t$.

One formula that I have seen is that $P = Fv$, i.e. power is the product of force and velocity. According to Wikipedia, this requires $v$ to be constant. Someone on this site, and someone I work with have both said that I need $v$ to be constant for $P=Fv$ to hold.

However, I found an article from 1930, which found equations of motion for constant power. Just like the standard equations of motion $v=u+at$, $v^2=u^2+2as$, $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$, and $s=\frac{1}{2}(u+v)t$ all *assume a constant force*, i.e. a constant acceleration, [L. W. Taylor (1930)](https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1811/2458/V30N04_218.pdf;jsessionid=A073FE21EB809A0296D62640B9CFD909?sequence=1) found six analogous formulae for motion under constant power. He used $P= Fv$ as his *definition* for power.

**Can I work with $P=Fv$, assuming that $F$ and $v$ vary, provided their product is constant?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a precise definition of power in the following question: [Why isn't the product rule used in the definition of mechanical work?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77935/why-isnt-the-product-rule-used-in-the-definition-of-mechanical-work/77937#77937).  Here is a reproduction of that text:

> For a particle traveling along a parameterized curve $\vec x(t)$ and under the influence of a force $\vec F(\vec x,t)$ which is explicitly dependent on both position in space and time, the work performed on the particle by this force from a time $t_0$ to a time $t$ is *defined* as follows:
>   \begin{align}
>   W_{t_0}(t) = \int_{t_0}^{t} \vec F(\vec x(t'),t')\cdot \dot{\vec x}(t') \,dt'
> \end{align}
>   Note that the expression on the right is often written $\int \vec F\cdot \vec dx$, but this is really schematic, the the mathematically precise definition is what I have written above in terms of a parameterized path with an integral over some range of parameter values.  The *definition* of instantaneous power is then
>   \begin{align}
>   P(t) = \dot W_{t_0}(t)
> \end{align}
>   Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $t$, and using the fundamental theorem of calculus, we obtain the desired expression for the power
>   \begin{align}
>   P(t) = \vec F(\vec x(t),t)\cdot \dot{\vec x}(t)
> \end{align}

Notice that the expression $\vec F\cdot \vec v$ is the instantaneous power for arbitrarily changing force and velocity.  There is not even a restriction on the constancy of their product.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $P = Fv$ always holds, even when neither the force, the velocity nor their product are constant. If you write:

$$ P(t) = F(t)v(t) $$

Then this is true at all times $t$ and gives the instantaneous power at the time $t$. Obviously if the velocity and/or force vary with time then the power will also vary with time.

Comment: Damn, Josh's answer is better, as usual :-)

Comment: John don't be ridiculous.  Our answers are exactly the same not to mention I pilfered an old post of mine which is pretty shady :)

Comment: How can one justify $P = Fv$, when $P = \dot{W}$ and $W = Fs$. The product rule gives 
$\dot{W} = \dot{F}s+F\dot{s} = m\dot{a} + Fv$
Don't we need $\dot{a}=0$, i.e. $v$ constant?

Comment: @FlybyNight: this is discussed in the question Josh linked, http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77935/why-isnt-the-product-rule-used-in-the-definition-of-mechanical-work.